# Datatables, jQuery: Clientside or serverside processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a database table with up to 30.000 entries and 20-25 columns that I want to show in my datatables-table.

Do I need serverside processing in this scale or can I send all the data down to the client and client-process everything (like filter and stuff)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely, server side pagination and sorting is a must. Leave datatables or any other plugin aside, simple html would be painfully slow for 30000 rows. Still, if you want to have an idea how it would perform, look at this http://jsfiddle.net/UvjnT/2374/.

```
Dummy Code as stackoverflow wont let me put a jsfiddle without code and it doesnt make sense to put a code for something like this
```

Comment: :D, just wanted to put an emoji but stackoverflow wouldnt let me put just an emoji